# High TTFB after moving WordPress multisite from Windows to Linux

Tags: php, linux, wordpress, apache, amazon-web-services

I was recently put in charge of moving a large WordPress Multisite installation off some unreliable static Windows servers onto Linux servers which could easily be autoscaled with AWS. It has not gone swimmingly.

On the Windows hosts, the TTFB was roughly 200 ms. On my Linux servers, the TTFB is consistently over 3 seconds.

I'm running the stock AWS Linux image, which is CentOS, with Apache and PHP 5.6. The same database has been used.

I'm a bit of a Linux novice, so clearly something has been misconfigured. Can I get some pointers from someone better versed in configuring Apache/ PHP on Linux?

Thus far google has been unhelpful. From the standard suggestions, I've disabled DNS lookup in the Apache config and have it running MPM as Worker. If any particular configuration files would help, let me know and I'll upload them.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up answering this one myself. One thing which was missing from the description was that I'm using AWS EFS to host the site files... there's massive latency there. Waiting for suggestions from AWS support now.